# Page Expiration in Java(Wicket)

Tags: java, google-maps, frameworks, wicket

I'm writing a wicket project for a social network.In my project i have authentication so when a user enter address of the home page he is redirected to login page in this way:

```
public class MyApplication extends WebApplication {

    private Folder uploadFolder = null;

    @Override
    public Class getHomePage() {
        return UserHome.class;
    }

    public Folder getUploadFolder()
    {
        return uploadFolder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();

        // Disable the Ajax debug label!
        //getDebugSettings().setAjaxDebugModeEnabled(false);


        this.getMarkupSettings().setDefaultMarkupEncoding("UTF-8");
        this.getRequestCycleSettings().setResponseRequestEncoding("UTF-8");
        mountBookmarkablePage("/BossPage", BossPage.class);
        mountBookmarkablePage("/Branch", EditProfile.class);
        mountBookmarkablePage("/SA", SuperAdmin.class);
        mountBookmarkablePage("/Admin", ir.pnusn.branch.ui.pages.administratorPages.EditProfile.class);
        mountBookmarkablePage("/Student", StudentSignUP.class);
        mountBookmarkablePage("/Student/Test", StudentSignUpConfirm.class);
        mountBookmarkablePage("/Branch/categories.xml", CategoriesXML.class);

        get().getPageSettings().setAutomaticMultiWindowSupport(true);
        getResourceSettings().setThrowExceptionOnMissingResource(false);
        uploadFolder = new Folder("C:\\", "wicket-uploads");
        uploadFolder.mkdirs();

        this.getSecuritySettings().setAuthorizationStrategy(WiaAuthorizationStrategy.getInstance());
        this.getSecuritySettings().setUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener(WiaAuthorizationStrategy.getInstance());
        addComponentInstantiationListener(new IComponentInstantiationListener() {

            public void onInstantiation(final Component component) {
                if (!getSecuritySettings().getAuthorizationStrategy().isInstantiationAuthorized(component.getClass())) {
                    try {
                        getSecuritySettings().getUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener().onUnauthorizedInstantiation(component);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("ERRORRRRRRR:" + e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and my WiaAuthorizationStrategy class is like this which will get page names and user roles from a xml file by name Realm.xml :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ir.pnusn.ui.library;

import ir.pnusn.authentication.RealmPolicy;
import ir.pnusn.authentication.ui.pages.Login;
import org.apache.wicket.Component;
import org.apache.wicket.RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException;
import org.apache.wicket.authorization.Action;
import org.apache.wicket.authorization.IAuthorizationStrategy;
import org.apache.wicket.authorization.IUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener;

public final class WiaAuthorizationStrategy implements
        IAuthorizationStrategy,
        IUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener {

    private RealmPolicy roleManager;
    private static WiaAuthorizationStrategy instance;

    private WiaAuthorizationStrategy() {
        roleManager = RealmPolicy.getInstance();
    }

    public static WiaAuthorizationStrategy getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new WiaAuthorizationStrategy();
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isInstantiationAuthorized(Class componentClass) {

        if (ProtectedPage.class.isAssignableFrom(componentClass)) {
            if (WiaSession.get().getUser() == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if(!roleManager.isAuthorized(WiaSession.get().getUser().getRole(), componentClass.getName()))//WiaSession.get().isAuthenticated();
            {
                WiaSession.get().setAccess(false);
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void onUnauthorizedInstantiation(Component component) {
        throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(
                Login.class);
    }

    public boolean isActionAuthorized(Component component, Action action) {
        //System.out.println("Name:" + component.getClass().getName() + "\n Action:" + action.getName() + "\nUser:" + WiaSession.get().getUser());
        if (action.equals(Component.RENDER)) {
            if (roleManager.containClass(component.getClass().getName()))
             {
                if (WiaSession.get().getUser() != null) {
                    if(!roleManager.isAuthorized(WiaSession.get().getUser().getRole(), component.getClass().getName()))
                    {
                        WiaSession.get().setAccess(false);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

in this situation i have a googlemap in one of my protectedpage and because googlemap needs to read data for loading builing from a xml so i create a servlet which will create it dynamicly depending on  the Username. this servlet is below:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ir.pnusn.branch.ui.pages;

import ir.pnusn.branch.database.BranchNotFoundException;



import ir.pnusn.branch.database.DatabaseException;
import ir.pnusn.branch.facade.admin.branchDataEnter.BranchDataSubmitFacade;
import ir.pnusn.branch.facade.admin.branchDataEnter.BuildingBean;


import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.wicket.PageParameters;
import org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;

/**
 *
 * @author mohammad
 */
public class CategoriesXML extends WebPage
{

    public CategoriesXML(PageParameters parameters)
    {
        System.out.println("user " + parameters.getString("user"));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<markers>");
        List<BuildingBean> buildings;
        try
        {
            buildings = BranchDataSubmitFacade.createBranchDataSubmitFacade(parameters.getString("user")).getBranchSecondPageData();
            for (Iterator<BuildingBean> it = buildings.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
            {
                BuildingBean buildingBean = it.next();
                builder.append("<marker lat=\"");
                builder.append(buildingBean.getLatit());
                builder.append("\" lng=\"");
                builder.append(buildingBean.getLongit());
                builder.append("\"");
                builder.append(" address=\"");
                builder.append(buildingBean.getDesctiption());
                builder.append("\" category=\"branch\" name=\"");
                builder.append(buildingBean.getBuildingName());
                builder.append("\"/>");

            }
            builder.append("</markers>");

        }
        catch (DatabaseException ex)
        {
            builder = new StringBuilder("<markers></markers>");
        }
        catch (BranchNotFoundException ex)
        {
            builder = new StringBuilder("<markers></markers>");
        }
        RequestCycle.get().getResponse().println(builder.toString());
        /*"<markers>" +
        "<marker lat=\"35.69187\" lng=\"51.413269\" address=\"Some stuff to display in the First Info Window\"  category=\"branch\" name=\"gholi\"/>" +
        "<marker lat=\"52.91892\"  lng=\"78.89231\" address=\"Some stuff to display in the Second Info Window\" category=\"branch\" name=\"taghi\"/>" +
        "<marker lat=\"40.82589\"  lng=\"35.10040\" address=\"Some stuff to display in the Third Info Window\"  category=\"branch\" name=\"naghi\"/>" +
        "</markers> "**/
    }
}
```

I have made this page at first protected and so the user had to loged in to have access this xml but after lot's of debuging i found that googlemap can't log in my system so instead of parsing the dataxml it pars login page html az input. so i changed the extention of the CategoriesXML to extend WebPage.
But now I have another problem:
When i go to the google map page in my Social site I can Not refresh the page because It expires and so I cannot add another building to my data xml.
what should I do?
tell me if you need more code or information

Comment: Have you thought to make your page stateless?

Comment: Initialize StringBuilder to its estimated maximum capacity to avoid multiple array resizes. Better yet, take Tim's advice and eliminate it altogether using the framework. See the "append" method impelmentation here for details: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In trying to close this question, which the OP seems to have pretty much abandoned, I'll just post my old comment as an answer..:

In your CategoriesXML I would highly advise against building and adding your tags as Strings and adding them to pages just like that. See if you can work this into a  in your .xml(?) file instead, as that's the Wicket way to do things (and as such just might solve the problems you're having)

Answer (score 1):

Would making this WebPage extends org.apache.wicket.Page instead and associate the markup to return as xml instead of html? Basically, mimicking a WebPage, but implementing it for XML.